# Adding .addClass to jQuery submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have created a jQuery submit form using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $form = $('form');
   $form.submit(function(){
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
        $('.rsvp-left').addClass('rsvp-hide');
        $('.rsvp-right').addClass('rsvp-hide');
        $('.rsvp-success').addClass('rsvp-show');
  },'json');
  return false;
   });
});
```

And I cannot seem to get the .addClass to work within this code.

The rest of the script works great, and the form submits properly without leaving the page, but the class changes will not execute.

I am trying to change the classes so that I can show that the form has been submitted correctly.

Any ideas on how I can make it work?

Comment: might be because your ajax request is sending an error response - inspect your ajax request using network tab of your browser developer tools and check the response status and response body

Comment: Add an error handler to see what value is returned like `$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
    alert('success')
    $('.rsvp-left').addClass('rsvp-hide');
    $('.rsvp-right').addClass('rsvp-hide');
    $('.rsvp-success').addClass('rsvp-show');
}, 'json').fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
    alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
});`

Comment: The above code breaks everything, and does not deliver an error.

I don't have a lot of experience testing ajax errors, but I looks in the Chrome developer tools and could not find any errors.  It was producing 200OK when I processed the command.

Comment: I just added an error handler `.fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
    alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
});` what did it break

Comment: also what is the response content... is it a json formatted content

Comment: When I try to run the error handle, it breaks the function that is creating performing the function behind the scenes.
The Response header is as follows:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 23 Feb 2014 06:56:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 14
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=30
Server: Apache/2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13

The code that is performing the action is PHP. Might that be causing this problem?

The form is located here: http://nwgg.co/tourny-page.php

Comment: if the response returns a 200Ok... then another possibility is it may not be a valid json response... so there might be a parseerror that is what I want to find out

Comment: as a debugging step change the datatype from `'json'` to `'text'` and check

Comment: When I changed the datatype to 'text' the execution worked properly, but it is constantly executing the code regardless of whether I press the button or not. So my SQL results page is filling with empty tables every few seconds.

Comment: Unless that is someone from stackoverflow submitting the form.

Comment: I was trying to get it submitted

Comment: the reason is your response is not a proper json response.... what is the expected response data format from your server

Comment: It appears to be working. When I changed the code from 'json' to 'text', it executed properly, and I was getting the results I wanted. Is there an issue with keeping it as 'text'?

Comment: no specific problem.... the data type should depend on what kind of data you are expecting from the server.... can you share a sample of the response content for better diagnosis

Comment: It is connecting to a PHP form which is connecting to MySQL, saving the response and presenting it in a table. Is that why the text is working properly? Because my response data format is not json?

Comment: looks like then you are using a html response in that case you have a `'html'` data type.... try it

Comment: yes the reason for your code not working is that, ie the data format is not json

Comment: For future reference, would you recommend using JSON to handle response code, and do you know of a good resource to understand that?

Comment: it depends on what kind of data you are working on.... in your current scenario from what I understand you are returning a html content as the response so html data type is perfect